# How check #id html template inside of ngIF directive?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have list inside of HTML template, where I created id like `#child`:

```
 <mat-selection-list #childs>
            <mat-list-option *ngFor="let child of ELEMENT_DATA">
              <span (click)="assignChild(child)">{{ child.firstName }}&nbsp;{{ child.lastName }}</span>
            </mat-list-option>
          </mat-selection-list>
```

In second phase I would like to check length inside of *ngIf. Question is: How can I pass `#child` to `*ngIf=""`? Thanks and regards.

Greg

Comment: what exactly would you like to achieve with `*ngIf`?

Comment: I would like to check if more than 0 opt is selected. I figured it out in correct way.